# Json deserialize into own class

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, json.net

I'm using asp.net mvc4 and [json.net](http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx)

and i have a json structure like http://api.domaintools.com/v1/domaintools.com/whois/

How can i deserialize it into my own class ? This looks a bit complicated structure to me to realize how to build my class ?

Nam Vo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following class structure:

```
       public class Response
       {
          public string Registrant {get;set;}
          public Registration registration {get;set;}
          public WhoIs whois {get;set;}
       }
       public class Registration
      {
          public DateTime created {get;set;}
          public DateTime expires {get;set;}
          public DateTime updated {get;set;}
          public string registrar {get;set;}
          public List<string> statuses {get;set;}
          public List<string> name_servers {get;set;}

      }
      public class WhoIs
      {
          public DateTime date {get;set;}
          public string record {get;set;}

      }
```

You can then do like below:

```
    Response response = JsonSerializer.DeserializeFromString<Response>(data);//data is your data from the link you have given in the problem description
```

Thus the data is now deserialized into your own class Response...hope this helps....